# pandas: replacing null values with average by group

Tags: python, pandas, replace, null

I am trying to replace null values in a column with the average according to the group from another column. I have tried this code and the null values are replaced but not correctly.
How so? How should I correct this?

the first two null values should be replaced by a 3 since they belong to group 'A' where the average is 3.
the following null value should be 4 since is located in group B that has 4,2,1,5 averaging 3.

column 'z' should have the following values: 3 3 3 5 3 1 2 4 6 9 10 5

```
xx=float('nan')
data=[['A', 1, xx ],
        ['B', 5,5],
        ['C', 4,6]
        ,['A', 6,xx],
        ['B',9,xx],
        ['C', 7,9]
        ,['A', 2,3],
        ['B', 5,1],
        ['C',2,10]
        ,['B', 8,2],
        ['B', 5,4],
        ['C', 8,5 ]]
dff = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','z'])

dff = dff.sort_values(by =['x'], ascending=True)
dff.reset_index(drop=True, inplace= True)
print(dff)

dff['z'] = df.groupby(['x'])['z'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
print(dff)
```

Comment: `dff['z'] = df.groupby(['x'])['z'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))` is correct.

Comment: the average of 4,2,1,5 is 3 not 4. Just to prevent confusion

Answer (score 2):

Replacing missing values can be done with `.fillna` and group averages with `groupby(...).mean(...)`.

A useful trick is to use `groupby.transform('mean')` which returns a series or dataframe of the original shape:

```
>>> dff.groupby('x')['z'].mean()
x
A    3.0
B    3.0
C    7.5
Name: z, dtype: float64
>>> dff.groupby('x')['z'].transform('mean')
0     3.0
1     3.0
2     3.0
3     3.0
4     3.0
5     3.0
6     3.0
7     3.0
8     7.5
9     7.5
10    7.5
11    7.5
Name: z, dtype: float64
```

Note that the average of group B is `3` not `4` as you expected.

So then it simply becomes:

```
>>> dff['z'].fillna(dff.groupby('x')['z'].transform('mean'))
0      3.0
1      3.0
2      3.0
3      5.0
4      3.0
5      1.0
6      2.0
7      4.0
8      6.0
9      9.0
10    10.0
11     5.0
Name: z, dtype: float64
```